# Should I actually use async-await in inner methods?

Tags: c#, async-await, dapper

Let's say I have 3 methods as follows:

```cs
public async Task<int> CalculateData(int index, int trustLevel, string type)
{
    var x = await CalculateBaseScore(index, type);
    return ComplexProcess(x, trustLevel);
}

public async Task<int> CalculateBaseScore(int index, string type)
{
    var conn_string = "...";
    var sql = "...";
    var param = new { Index = index, Type = type };
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(conn_string))
    {
        var db_output = await conn.ExecuteScalarAsync<int>(sql, param: param);
        return db_output;
    }
}

public int CalculateBaseScore(int index, int trustLevel)
{
    //Omitted
}
```

As you can see, 2 of them use async-await.

In Stephen Cleary's [introduction to async-await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html), it's said that

> If you *can* write it without await, then you *should* write it without await, and remove the async keyword from the method. A non-async method returning Task.FromResult is more efficient than an async method returning a value.

In this case, will a Dapper-made database call qualify as a method I can write without async-await and simply return a `Task<int>` object? Will I get any benefits in performance or other aspects if I change it to this?

```cs
public async Task<int> CalculateData(int index, int trustLevel, string type)
{
    var x = await CalculateBaseScore(index, type);
    return ComplexProcess(x, trustLevel);
}

public Task<int> CalculateBaseScore(int index, string type)
{
    var conn_string = "...";
    var sql = "...";
    var param = new { Index = index, Type = type };
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(conn_string))
    {
        var db_output_task = conn.ExecuteScalarAsync<int>(sql, param: param);
        return db_output_task;
    }
}

public int CalculateBaseScore(int index, int trustLevel)
{
    //Omitted
}
```

See tht in the second example, I omitted the async-await keywords on `CalculateBaseScore` and simply returned the `Task` object.

Comment: Here's a [helpful link](https://cpratt.co/async-tips-tricks/). Look for the heading "Eliding the async/await keywords." The answer is that yes, you can omit `async` and just return the task as you are in your Dapper example.

Comment: The question "will I get performance wins if I do X" can only be answered definitively by doing X and doing not X, and comparing a user-focussed, carefully-measured performance metric. The only person who can do that is you; if you have two horses and you want to know which is the faster, asking strangers on the internet who have never seen your horses to guess is not a substitute for simply racing the horses!

Comment: His information is outdated. While Task DOES have an overhead, there is a reason there is now ValueTask which is a struct and faster. This part is thus - simply outdated.

Comment: @TomTom: We did not create value tasks because they are *faster*. We created them because they lower collection pressure in the scenario where the task is likely already completed.

Comment: FWIW, you're not alone. in the past two years I've progressed from understanding async/await all wrong to mostly understanding it most of the time and googling the rest.

Comment: Also, as Theodor's answer points out, the question "which of these choices is faster?" requires that the two workflows being compared are *both correct* and *do the same thing*. Concentrate on that first!

Comment: I have changed my position in the intervening years, and I now [recommend against eliding `async`/`await`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html) except in the most trivial of cases. I shall update the older post right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the second implementation without async-await:

```
public Task<int> CalculateBaseScore(int index, string type)
{
    var conn_string = "...";
    var sql = "...";
    var param = new { Index = index, Type = type };
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(conn_string))
    {
        var db_output_task = conn.ExecuteScalarAsync<int>(sql, param: param);
        return db_output_task;
    }
}
```

...will give you a performance boost of around 1 μsec per invocation. In other words it will save you a whole second of CPU time after invoking it 1,000,000 times. These are the good news.

The bad news are that all these 1,000,000 invocations will result to an `ObjectDisposedException`, because the `SqlConnection` will be disposed prematurely, immediately after the creation of the `Task`.

Does it worth it? I'd say no. Keeping it simple will save you more time in the long run.

Comment: Excellent point; always remember that a workflow *must* have an `await` at positions in the workflow where the remainder of the workflow must not proceed until the earlier portion has *completed*. If it is a requirement that the cleanup code at the end of the workflow *not execute* until the beginning of the workflow is *complete* then there needs to be an `await`.